# How did scientists put forth or create the images of milky way galaxy

Tags: space-telescope, galactic

I understand telescopes were used to observe and capture images of other galaxies. But, by risking the question sounding pretty ordinary, may I know how did we take the pictures or photographs of our home, the milky way galaxy (the beautiful spiral that we all are familiar with as shown below), given that Voyager mission took 35 years to even reach the heliopause?

[image: Artist's rendition of milky way galaxy]

Source : [Universe Today](http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/milky_way.jpg)

I'm sure there has to be some technique the scientists use to do that. (They don't have galactic selfie cameras yet, do they?) Can someone throw some light on this topic?

Comment: This may be a better question for Astronomy SE, but as it concerns how those observations were done, *specifically* mentioning probe missions, I say it is weakly on topic here as well.

Comment: This question is very strange: it presumes that such pictures exist, while rightly being skeptical that such pictures should exist, and presents no examples of such a picture.

Comment: @RussellBorogove, I'm surprised by your comment. If I had my school textbooks, I would have taken a snap and posted. Anyone who knows to google can get a picture like [this](http://www.universetoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/milky_way.jpg). If you have something else on mind, kindly pose the question in a clear manner rather than being vague.

Comment: The first google image search hit I get for "milky way picture" takes me to a Universe Today page which (very responsibly) captions the picture '**Artist’s impression** of the Milky Way Galaxy, as seen from above the galactic “North pole". Credit: NASA' [bold mine].

Comment: @RussellBorogove, That's exactly my point. "Artist's Impression" doesn't mean some Picasso has grabbed his brush and did some magnificent strokes to get that out of his sheer imagination or something. I dunno how that works but he sure is guided by some scientific approach or method to get that picture. That is what I wanted to know about. Anyways, I got my answer from the replies below. Maybe modifying the topic/header would help and I just did that.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit it might be better if you include at least a link to one or two specific examples of the kinds of images you are talking about, or included an image within your question - with the link to the source. It's not necessary since in this case they clearly can't be real images, but in general it's good to include specific examples in questions where possible, within stackexchange questions.

Comment: @uhoh, just included an image just as you suggested.

Comment: "...or included an image within your question - *with the link to the source*." It's best to credit the source of an image whenever possible. I know some images seem to be literally all over the internet, but it's important here both because of IP license issues, and it sometimes helps people trying to answer the question to review the source.

Comment: You can see that [pics about space](https://pics-about-space.com/milky-way-galaxy-sun?p=1#img11675145677664170718) credits [sun.org](http://www.sun.org/images/the-milky-way-galaxy) which credits Wikipedia (though no link) and shows *Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good question and on-topic as far as I'm concerned. As you correctly point out our furthest reaching spacecraft is only at the heliopause, which is no real distance astronomically, and certainly not far enough to get a glimpse of our galaxy from an angle and distance which would allow that self-portrait. The images of the milky way galaxy are all artistic renditions, they are educated guesses of what our galaxy would look like based on observations of other galaxies and our own. Concentrations of matter have been extensively mapped in our galaxy using visible light and spectrum outside the visible range like infrared, x-rays, and others. These concentrations of matter show the structure of our galaxy even though we cannot observe it from an angle.

The next logical question is how do we know they are right, and the answer is we don't, not with absolute certainty. The map of our galaxy is based on observations from a single point, and interpreted using an understanding of the physical laws of our universe as developed over hundreds (or thousands) of years by some of the finest minds in history. Yet for all of the effort and brainpower it is still within the realm of possibility that this understanding is wrong in which case our map may be wrong.

It's going to take a long time before anyone gets far enough away to check that work in any case.

Comment: I have read about and seen artistic renditions for supernovas, blackholes etc (Some of them looking like taken right out of the pages of a fantasy comic book). So, they are all sort of guessworks? Since milky way is visible in the night sky, these artistic renditions should have used that as a reference and bits and pieces of whatever information available and create the image, right?

Comment: I hate to use the word guesswork, a better way to put it would be the best science possible with only one point of reference. You are essentially correct though.

Comment: @skrowten_hermit: Some of images of Milky Way are much more than guesswork - no more a guesswork than a map is a guesswork. We know how *a generic galaxy* looks from above, and we know the precise layout of Milky Way, so we can generate a very accurate rendition of how it looks like.

Comment: Your point is entirely valid @SF. and I don't think we disagree on it. The map of our galaxy is based on observations made from a single point, interpreted as best as possible using our understanding of the physical laws of the universe.

Answer (score 5):

We can't take photos of our own galaxy that show the beautiful spiral. From astronomical observations (both from the ground and from satellites like Gaia) we do have lots of data on stars inside our galaxy, including their positions. So we can create a visualization that shows the known stars and their positions. Part of the Milky Way is obscured by dust clouds, so in those directions the visualization has to include some guesswork.

This map shows [radio telescope observations](http://www.atlasoftheuniverse.com/milkyway.html) of the Milky Way. Gray and red are observations. The mostly-black cone radiating upward from our position (at +, straight below the center of the image) is an obscured area.

[image: Milky Way hydrogen map]

Comment: Though I was unaware of such a technique, I had a hunch that some mapping process might be involved. Radio telescopes work in the same way a Radar or Sonar works?

Comment: A radio telescope is a passive system, radar and sonar are usually active (they send out a signal and listen for its reflection). In this case, the radio telescope listens for transmissions made by hydrogen atoms. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_telescope